# C++ Word Wrap Within Column

Tags: c++, word-wrap, iomanip

I need to output some columns in c++ that look like this:

```
          Lower  Upper
   Line   case   case   Digits Spaces Other
   ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```

To print out some results from a file read, etc, etc.

Is there anyway to do word wrap in c++ on with a setw(6)???

My code looks like this:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <iomanip>

   using namespace std;

   void printLines(); // declaring

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

          // print table headings
      cout << setw(6) << "Line" << setw(1) << " ";
      cout << setw(6) << "Lower case" << setw(1) << " ";
      cout << setw(6) << "Upper case" << setw(1) << " ";
      cout << setw(6) << "Digits" << setw(1) << " ";
      cout << setw(6) << "Spaces" << setw(1) << " ";
      cout << setw(6) << "Other" << endl;

       printLines();


   };

   // function to output 5 "lines" to divide the table headings from the data

   void printLines() {

       for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

           cout << setfill('-') << setw(6); // set output fill
           cout << "-" << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << " ";

       };

       return;

   };
```

But my output looks like this:

```
  Line Lower case Upper case Digits Spaces  Other
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: `setw` only defines a *minimum*  length.  It does nothing if the data exceeds that length.

Comment: You will need to print your "longer than 6" as two lines (using "empty" string as the filler for those that aren't long).

Comment: Ahh, that's what I figured. Just wondering if there was another way to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest writing out HTML and then viewing it with your browser.\

Comment: :) That's a great idea. Wish that was the assignment.